# Changing webcam orientation in javascript (media devices)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, electron, webcam

I'm creating an Electron app that needs to take a picture from the webcam to continue. Problem is: I need the camera view to be vertical (like the phones). I have a Logitech c922 pro stream.

**Code**

```
function startup() {
    video = document.getElementById('video');
    canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    photo = document.getElementById('photo');
    startbutton = document.getElementById('startbutton');

    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: {
        width: { min: 270, max: 270 },
        height: { min: 480, max: 480},
        frameRate: 60,
    }, audio: false })
    .then(function(stream) {
        video.srcObject = stream;
        video.play();
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
        console.log("An error occured! " + err);
    });

    video.addEventListener('canplay', function(ev) {
        if (!streaming) {
            canvas.setAttribute('width', width*ar);
            canvas.setAttribute('height', height);
            streaming = true;
        }
    }, false);

    startbutton.addEventListener('click', function(ev) {
        takepicture();
        ev.preventDefault();
        print();
    }, false);

    clearphoto();
}
```

Comment: "I need the camera view to be vertical" - I don't understand what this means

Comment: @pushkin I mean like a phone, on the phone you can rotate de camera and you still see the things in the right position, meanwhile in this webcam, it follows all the stuff, example, if I rotate de camera 90deg I would see a person standing from the right to the left, instead of bottom to top.

Comment: Ok I found a solution, just adding this canvas attributes: `code context.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, width);
      context.rotate(-90 * Math.PI / 180);` and set the size of the canvas to match.